# Show $f(x) = x\ln (1 + \frac{a}{x})$ is increasing when $x>0$ for any $a>0$ without using derivatives

Tags: calculus

The question is to show

> $f(x) = x\ln (1 + \frac{a}{x})$ is increasing when $x>0$ for any $a>0$

Taking derivatives can solve the problem, but that looks clumsy. Can anyone help think of any other method? Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your definition of "clumsy" to be specific. Are you in search of a method that looks elegant and doesn't use derivatives? Or would you accept an elegant answer that does use derivatives?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If $0 < x < y$, then $\dfrac{1}{1+\frac t x} < \dfrac{1}{1+\frac t y}$ for all $t > 0$. By integrating over $[0,a]$, we obtain therefore
$$
x\ln\left(1+\frac  a x\right) = \int_0^a\frac{dt}{1+\frac t x} < \int_0^a\frac{dt}{1+\frac t y} = y\ln\left(1+\frac  a y\right) 
$$

Comment: Nice! Isn't it using derivatives in disguise, though? (the starting point is the derivative of the function $(x,a)\mapsto f(x,a)$ with regard to $a$, instead of $x$)

Comment: @ClementC. The $\ln$ function is usually **defined** as the primitive of $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}$ on $(0,+\infty)$ such that $\ln(1)=0$. This is all I need.

Comment: @ClementC. But of course, I agree with your remark even though I feel that what the OP wants to avoid is taking the (clumsy) derivative with respect to $x$.

Comment: sure -- that's also how i interpret the question (since the OP defines $f$ as a function of $x$ only).

Answer (score 1):

Substitute $x\leftarrow \frac{a}{e^t-1}$ (which is decreasing as $x$ increases). Then the claim is that $$t\mapsto g(t)=\frac{at}{e^t-1}$$
is decreasing (for $t>0$). Note that $g$ is positive, so this is equivalent to saying that 
$$ t\mapsto h(t)=\frac a{g(t)}=\frac{e^t-1}{t}$$
is increasing. But this a direct consequence of  $\exp$ being convex, done.